# Why does Apple require NSCameraUsageDescription even though my app does not use the camera?

Tags: ios, permissions, camera, ios10

What it says on the label. Now that iOS 10 is out, Apple started enforcing the requirement of warning the users about privacy-related issues with apps. However, my app has never used the camera, and most likely never will. It is currently available on the App Store, and it was approved when iOS 9 was the latest and greatest.

I uploaded my latest build for approval, and the automated processing rejected it because It's missing the `NSCameraUsageDescription` key in the Info.plist file. The best I can figure is that they scan the binary for linked libraries and frameworks that might use the camera. I thought I removed all of them, but I still get the error. Here is the list.

Social
Crashlytics
Fabric
ImageIO
MobileCoreServices
Foundation
UIKit
OpenGLES
QuartzCore
SystemConfiguration
CoreGraphics
AudioToolbox
StoreKit
Accelerate
Security
CoreText

The app is based on [Cinder](https://libcinder.org) and I already removed all the frameworks that were marked as optional. There is really nowhere around the code that might ever require the camera, not even access to the camera roll!

I'm a bit at a loss. Any pointers?

Comment: Are using any third party controls?

Comment: No third party controls, the app is very minimal (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/circular-bells/id1062362784?mt=8)

Comment: @Morpheu5 How did you solve it?

Comment: I did not. I think a possible solution is to make a custom build of Cinder that only includes the necessary parts.